# Magento. How to extend and use default products picture uploader?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

i have created my own grid in magento admin panel and add few tabs. In one tab i need to display same picture uploader like in creating product page.

I mean this block:
**Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php**

here is how i create the tab

```
$this->addTab('images_uploader', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images Uploader'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Images Uploader'),
        'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_helper_form_gallery_content')->toHtml(),
    ));
```

but i get error 
**Call to a member function getDataObject() on a non-object app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php on line 164**